# How to replace Class and text to Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, addclass

Trying to replace Class and Text to Buttons, there have three list items, list 1 and 2 is same class, list 3 has is different class that's alrady added dynamically. There have two buttons like `<button class="one"></button>` and `<button class="two"></button>`.

Now want to place class and text, like place any class and text from list inside the button,
like: `<button class="one text1">text1</button>` and `<button class="two text2">text2</button>` HTML given below.

Please see this [example image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-2fCy9JwPT_8/VdlEqJlUQCI/AAAAAAAAB_E/yJr66_Ly7kY/s1600/example.png) > (I wish)

**HTML:** Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ts8Lcpa/4/)

```
<div id="main-id">

<button class="one"></button>  
    <button class="two"></button>  

<ul>

<li class="text1"> <!--List 1-->
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="text1"> <!--List 2 is Same-->
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="text2"> <!--List 3 is different-->
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried this 'Replacetext' [script](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-replacetext/examples/replacetext/), but i'm unable to do that. Any suggestion for other way to do this? 
*My question agin:* Want replace the text and class to each button dynamically get from list items. Not need link or no click function. Output should be like this :`<button class="one text1">text1</button>` dynamically, it should execute automatically/on load. please see the given image. jQuery/javascript as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey mate, could you please be more specific. I read your post a bunch of times and I still don't get it. Do you want to replace the text of each button dynamically? or the texts in the list.

One more thing, replaceText script is a custom script. Are you using jQuery, or just pure javascript?

Comment: Yes, want replace the text and class of each button dynamically. jQuery or javascript you wish.

Comment: Kay, give me a few minutes to re-do the fiddle. I'll add a few ids to make it easy to identify things.

Comment: What's the idea to link a button to a list item? are those fixed? or this is gonna be dynamic?

Comment: No link or no click function. Output should like this : `<button class="one text1">text1</button>` dynamically. it should execute automatically/on load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87672/discussion-between-aabira-and-bob-rosset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

If you want it on page load

```
$('button').each(function(){
    var liInd = 0;
    var cl = '';
    var txt = '';
    var clses = [];

    var ind = $('button').index($(this)) + 1;

    $('li').each(function(){
        if(clses.indexOf($(this).attr('class')) === -1){
            clses.push($(this).attr('class'));
            liInd = liInd + 1;
        }

        if(ind === liInd){
            cl = $(this).attr('class');
            txt = $(this).find('a').text();
            return false; //break
        }
    });

    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').addClass(cl);
    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').text(txt);
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/7ts8Lcpa/23/

---

To do this when a list is clicked the following code should do the trick. (I've left this part so that the comments section make sense)

```
$('li').click(function () {
    var ind = 0;
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    var txt = $(this).find('a').text();
    var clses = [];

    $('li').each(function () {

        if (clses.indexOf($(this).attr('class')) == -1) {
            clses.push($(this).attr('class'));
            ind = ind + 1;

        }

        if ($(this).attr('class') === cl) {
            return false; // break 
        }

    });

    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').addClass(cl);
    $('button:nth-child(' + ind + ')').text(txt);
    return false;
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/5mbnfdf8/1/

Comment: Thanks, but why click function? also it's not working, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ts8Lcpa/18/   - i'm trying to add class and text to buttons from List items dynamically.

Comment: I thought you are trying to achieve this on click of the list. When do you want the text and classes to be copied to button? Do you want this on page load??

Comment: Thanks dear, but i want to replace it automatically/on load, please suggest.

Comment: OK, sure, i'm waiting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87673/discussion-between-aabira-and-taleeb).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').click(function(e){
var class = $(this).attr('class')
if (class == 'one'){
$(this).addClass('text1')
$(this).innerHtml($('.text1 a').innerHtml)
}else{
$(this).addClass('text2')
$(this).innerHtml($('.text1 a').innerHtml)
}
```

### }

or :

```
$('button').click(function(e){
var key=$(this).attr('key')
$('li').each(function(e)({
if (key == value){
var result=$(this).attr('class')
var text = $(this).innerhtml()
}
$(this).addclass(result)
$(this).innerhtml(text)
}
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="main-id">

<button class="one" key='1'></button>  
    <button class="two" key='2'></button>  

<ul>

<li class="text1" value='1'> <!--List 1-->
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="text1" value='1'> <!--List 2 is Same-->
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text1</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="text2" value='2'> <!--List 3 is different-->
<div class="label">
<a href="http://lorem.com">text2</a>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but not need link or no click function. Output should be like this :`<button class="one text1">text1</button>` dynamically, it should execute automatically/on load.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
    <div id="main-id">

<button class="one"></button>  
    <button class="two"></button>  

<ul>

<li class="text1"> <!--List 1-->
<div class="label">
<a href="#">text1</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="text1"> <!--List 2 is Same-->
<div class="label">
<a href="#">text1</a>
</div>
</li>

<li class="text2"> <!--List 3 is different-->
<div class="label">
<a href="#">text2</a>
</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

> JS:

```
$('.text1').click(function(){
   var btn_one = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0],
    this_class = $(this).attr('class'),
    this_text = $(this).text();
   $(btn_one).attr('class',this_class);
   $(btn_one).html(this_text);
});

$('.text2').click(function(){
   var btn_two = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1],
    this_class = $(this).attr('class'),
    this_text = $(this).text();
   $(btn_two).attr('class',this_class);
   $(btn_two).html(this_text);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Grald/16qcakpv/

Comment: Hi thanks, but how to do this without click function?

Comment: What trigger you want to use aside from click?

Comment: Just remove the click function method if u want it onload event.

Answer (score 1):

based on the chat. What you want is this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.one').addClass( $('.text1').attr('class') ).text( $('.text1').find('.label a').html() ).removeClass('one');
    $('.two').addClass( $('.text2').attr('class') ).text( $('.text2').find('.label a').html() ).removeClass('two');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrosset/7abue6vm/10/

I don't understand the reason yet, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks i'm going to ask  same question in new way, i will give you the link, please wait .

Comment: Hi, are you there? This is my question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32163672/4290783

Comment: Sorry mate, it was really late Yesterday when you sent me the new link, but I saw your question already has an answer, good to read that! :D